Determine size_t in llvmlite
I am trying to write some code in llvmlite that calls malloc. The only argument to malloc has type size_t. This type does not exist in LLVM and is presumably either llvmlite.ir.IntType(32) or llvmlite.ir.IntType(64) depending on the target machine. How do I get the pointer size for the default target (i.e. the current machine)?
import llvmlite.ir as llvm

module = llvm.Module()

# How do I do better than this?
pointer_type = llvm.IntType(64)

# Declare malloc
malloc_signature = llvm.FunctionType(llvm.IntType(8).as_pointer(), [pointer_type])
malloc = llvm.Function(module, malloc_signature, name="malloc")

